# Show documentation window crashes XCode 12

Tags: xcode

Just showing the Documentation Window crashes XCode 12 (cmd-shit-0) - anytime I do it.
Does anybody have the same problem, an explanation or a work around ?

Comment: Maybe documentation as a whole is not working. I experienced the crash when clicking on the side panel's quick help documentation link.

Comment: Same problem here.  Removed my GM for the app store version, now cannot open the developer documentation at all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update:** There's now a new version (12.0.1) in the App Store that fixes this issue.

I'm experiencing the same when using the version from the App Store. People in [this Apple Forums thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/660490) are reporting that it doesn't occur with the GM download from Apple's developer resources, despite the build identifiers being exactly the same.

Anecdotally, I can confirm that I was able to use documentation in the GM version before I deleted it in favor of the App Store version. So this may in fact be a viable workaround until the App Store version is fixed.

Comment: Same here — deleting the App Store version and downloading then installing the GM version (XIP file) did the trick. They have identical version numbers, *Version 12.0 (12A7209)*. Reported the bug to Apple as I'm sure others have too.

Answer (score 1):

The Xcode on the app store is some sort of unknown version, (Since there it release even before the GM version available). So get rid of it and **[Download The Xcode From The developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/)** or click the proper version below. Then it. will work like a charm.

<sub>This needs you. to login to your account</sub>

<sub>Don't forget to remove the appstore version downloaded Xcode</sub>

---

## Direct  Download

#### Xcode 12

[image: Xcode 12]

#### Xcode 12.2 Beta

[image: Xcode 12.2 Beta]

Answer (score 0):

I use xcode 12 beta 5 works well can open document window, when I upgrade to GM seed, it can not open document window any more. When I fallback to xcode 12 beta ,open document it crash every time. All these happened on mbp13 pro, but my another mbp 15 with the same macos version works very well.

I guess it have something with macOS system, not xcode version.

Now I upgrade xcode by AppStore ,crash all the same.